# Clear notifications from the notification center on button click

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, notifications, swift3

I want to clear the local push notifications of the app from the notification center on click of a button which is present inside the app.

Comment: What do you mean? Push notifications? Apple Notification center didn't store they.

Comment: is it remote notificaiton or local one ?

Comment: local push notifications.

Comment: do you want clear all local LocalNotifications ?

Comment: only the one which are linked to my app.

Answer (score 1):

On iOS before 10 you could only achieve that by setting `applicationIconBadgeNumber` to 0. With iOS 10 you can modify individual notifications using `UNUserNotificationCenter` framework.

Comment: Can you elaborate abit more, what exactly you are trying to explain.

Answer (score 0):

please use this code it will be help you out

```
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:1];
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:0];

 // To remove the notifications in Notification Center:
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
int badgeCount = [UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber;
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:0];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:badgeCount];
```